# Stands or standing in the shade of a tree

Tags: tense, present-tense

1)She **stands** in the shade of a tree.

2)She is **standing** in the shade of a tree.

One of the grammar books says that the first sentence is incorrect and second is correct.  Suggestions please.

Comment: They're both perfectly fine and have their uses. The first is more likely to be used in a poetic or literary context: *she stands in the shade of the tree, remembering the first time they met*.

Answer (score 2):

Both are perfectly valid. The first is simple present and the second is present continuous. Technically, the first says what she is doing at one particular instant, while the second says what she is doing over a period of time. But in practice, they mean pretty much the same thing. There might be a difference given the surrounding context.

Answer (score -1):

the **stand** is a STATIVE VERB, which does not admit the progressive action
Hence stands will be more appropriate for the above sentence.

Comment: You should back your answer up with reputable references. Both example sentences are correct. A little research would probably explain why.